# echo not printing next line unix bash

Tags: bash, unix, echo, newline

In my shell script, I have using below code:

```
RECORD=`ps -ef | grep sysProj | cut -d" " -f1,2`
echo $RECORD
```

on executing this, its printing

```
45646654 28770 45646654 32021 45646654 32176
```

but when I don't save command output in variable and executing as below:

```
ps -ef | grep sysProj | cut -d" " -f1,2
```

the output is:

```
45646654 28770
45646654 32021
45646654 32176
```

Why saving the command output in varible is suppressing new line character. Also, how can I retain it?

Comment: Also use lowercase for your script variables as full uppercase variables are usuallu system variables

Comment: See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just enclose the variable within double quotes to avoid [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting):

```
echo "$RECORD"
```